# Authentication fails for REST requests to Shopware 5 using Postman

Tags: api, postman, shopware

When making REST requests like GET `http://<url-to-shop>/api/articles` to my own Shopware 5 instance I always get

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Invalid or missing auth"
}
```

as a response, even though I provide the correct credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by going to `http://<url-to-shop>/backend` then to Settings -> User Administration -> edit User -> enable Api Access. Then I have to use the username of the user that I just enabled the API access for and most importantly I have to use the **API-Key as the password** in postman under the option **Basic Auth** like so:

[image]

Of course this also works with any other API-testing tool like Paw and others. I hope this saves you some time if you are trying to get this to work. Nowhere in the official documentation of Shopware 5 does it say that you are supposed to use the Api-Key as the password. They only write that the Api-Key is supposed to be "included" in the request: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#basic-settings .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the URL defined in Config and i used without www.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you misspelled: "i used without www"

Comment: What is the purpose of the second part of your post "and i used without www"? Is that part of the answer? Does it explain how the first part works? Does it explain why the first part helps?